# How to use MacOS Screen Sharing to access second account on same machine

Tags: macos, network, screen-sharing

I have two user accounts, personal and work.
I used to have two machines, a desktop and a laptop. Laptop had personal account, and I would use the work desktop with Screen Sharing to have both accounts accessible to me with a simple four finger swipe (with Screen Sharing in full-screen mode).

Now I have only one machine with both accounts on it. I can no longer use the above trick to have quick access to both user accounts, because Screen Sharing doesn't allow me to access localhost. I cannot use Fast User Switching, as it is not fast, but more importantly it logs me out of an important App I use each time I switch.

Is there some way to trick Screen Sharing into thinking I'm not trying to reach localhost and let me connect to my second user account? I do have access to an Ubuntu desktop on my network, if that helps any...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151151/can-i-remote-desktop-to-another-user-on-the-same-machine

Comment: @JacobVanus, that worked perfectly, thanks! How can I give you credit for it, do you want to post an answer and I will choose it?